# Como Traduzir "Pastoral" para o Inglês

Tags: tradução, termos-em-inglês

Estava discutindo com alguns colegas em como traduzir algums temos usados na igreja católica mas não chegamos a um consenso em vários.

- **Pastoral** - ex; Pastoral da Juventude, Pastoral da Criança.
- **Paróquia/Paroquial** - ex: Sistema de Gestão Paroquial e Diocesano.
- **Côngrua** - "Salário" do clero.
- **Eclesial** - e.g.: Direito Canônico e Tribunal Eclesiástico.
- **Ecônomo** - Membro do clero responsável pela contabilidade da diocese.

Como traduzi-los para o inglês?
Note que pesquisando em sites como a Wikipedia achei alguns termos, mas se possível gostaria de encontrar exemplos de sites em inglês ou saber de pessoas que tenham pelo menos ouvido se o termo é realmente usado nessa língua.

Comment: Que termos encontraste? Paróquia é parish; os outros, não faço ideia.

Comment: A Pastoral da Juventude (PJ), é um organismo de ação social católica da América Latina. Ou seja, é um termo oficial deles. A melhor tradução da ideia é: ***Youth Ministry*** https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastoral_da_Juventude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Pastoral (no sentido de [Ação pastoral católica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pastoral_cat%C3%B3lica)):

  - **[Ministry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_ministry)**: *Child Ministry*,*Youth Ministry*, "[*Homeless Ministry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeless_ministry)" (sugerido pelo [Lambie](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/917));
  - **Pastoral action/care**: *Child's Pastoral Action*, *Pastoral Care of the Child*;
    Encontrado na versão em inglês da [Pastoral da Criança](https://www.pastoraldacrianca.org.br/en/who-we-are), e nos artigos [Motherhood, body care and "civilization" in the Pastoral da Criança](http://socialsciences.scielo.org/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0104-026X2007000100004) e ["Why am i a volunteer?": building a quantitative scale](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1413-23112013000300002). [Existe](http://www.parche.org.uk/) também uma organização britânica chamada PARCHE ("Pastoral Action in Residential Care Homes for the Elderly").
    **Nota**: como bem observado nessa [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5841/2764), *pastoral* no sentido aqui usado é um adjetivo, não um substantivo, então *Child's Pastoral* é a rigor incorreto, por mais que seja encontrado em fontes como o site da própria Pastoral.
    **Nota**: como Lambie observou, "Child's Pastoral Action" pode ser indesejável, ao dar margem à interpretação de que a ação é realizada pela criança, ao invés de para ela.
  - **[Apostolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostolate)**: *Children's Apostolate* (a partir dessa [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5841/2764));
- Paróquia/Paroquial: **parish**, por [qualquer dicionário](http://www.wordreference.com/enpt/parish).
- Côngrua:

  - **stipend** ou **[sustentatio] congrua**, se referindo ao salário do clérigo ([Enciclopédia Católica](https://www.catholic.com/encyclopedia/stipend));
  - **Episcopal Subsidies**, se referindo às contribuições dos fieis feitas à diocese ([Enciclopédia Católica](https://www.catholic.com/encyclopedia/episcopal-subsidies)), que é o significado dado pela [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/c%C3%B4ngrua) à "côngrua" (*O que os habitantes de uma freguesia pagam ao pároco para sua sustentação.*).
- Eclesial: **[ecclesiastical](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ecclesiastical)**, **ecclesiastic**, **clerical**, **pastoral**, etc.
- Ecônomo:

  - [**Episcopal oeconomus**](https://www.catholic.com/encyclopedia/episcopal-oeconomus);
  - [**oeconomus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oikonomos);
  - [**ecclesiastical administrator**](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=ec%C3%B3nomo), [**diocesan finance officer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oikonomos) e qualquer outra expressão que signifique literalmente *tesoureiro da igreja*, ou seja, algum adjetivo que denote a ligação com a igreja aplicado a **bursar**, **tresurer**, etc.

Comment: +1. Mas ainda vou esperar por mais respostas. Nas minhas pesquisas achei o site da pastoral da criança mas a tradução não está 100% então foi uma das fontes que me gerou dúvida

Comment: @jean Sim, essa é uma tradução mais complicada, até porque se trata do nome de uma invenção brasileira. Atualizei a resposta com mais duas referências.

Comment: Children's Pastoral action is wrong; the children don't do the action. The "action" is delivered to them: Youth Ministry.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks. I'd change to "Child Ministry", since "Youth Ministry" might be a better fit for "Pastoral do Menor" ("Underage Ministry" certainly sounds strange). But I'm not convinced "Child's Pastoral Action" is wrong, I think it could parallel [Children's Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_hospital), which doesn't belong to the children, but it is for them, as the "Pastoral Action" would be.

Comment: I meant Pastoral Juventude= Youth Ministry

Answer (score 1):

Pastoral da Criança em inglês não é "Children's Pastoral", a tradução usada no site indicado está inadequada. Em inglês, "pastoral", no contexto religioso, é um adjetivo, usado como "pastoral duties" ou "pastoral work", ou seja, algo relativo ao trabalho de um pastor. Um termo que se aproxima mais disso é "apostolate", sendo definido como "2. An association of individuals for the dissemination of a religion or doctrine." pelo American Heritage Dictionary.

Um dos exemplos usados para ilustrar o verbete é muito indicativo do sentido: "In the past 12 months the Social Apostolate has obtained birth certificates for more than 800 homeless persons."

Mais uma prova de que não se pode confiar em fontes nativas de outro idioma para se conhecer termos em inglês uma vez que brasileiros, nesse caso, não são autoridade em inglês e o nome no site em questão foi visivelmente traduzido com base em um falso cognato. Não é porque o site traduzido para inglês de uma instituição usa determinada palavra que ela é a opção correta. A se confiar nesse tipo de tradução manca, "terceirização" poderia bem ser "terceirization" uma vez que aparece em abstracts da USP -- o termo correto é "outsourcing", mas os irresponsáveis preferiram usar a regra do "rebolation" e usar qualquer besteira em vez de pesquisar a palavra correta.

Comment: Ótimo ponto. Vou atualizar minha resposta em vista da sua.

Comment: Youth ministry....is the idea.

Comment: *Em inglês, "pastoral", no contexto religioso, é um adjetivo* - Em português também; a "Pastoral da Terra" é a "Comissão Pastoral da Terra". Em inglês seria "Pastoral Committee".